How to Simultaneously Load and Autoplay Multiple MP4 Videos on a Pure HTML Page Without Stopping?
I have a pure HTML page (no frameworks like React or Vue) that needs to load and autoplay six MP4 videos, each approximately 800KB in size. My goal is to make them play simultaneously without any of them stopping.
I've tried using the preload attribute, but it didn't solve the issue. Most of the time, some videos stop while others continue to play.
What techniques can I use to ensure that all videos load fully and play simultaneously without stopping?
Are there any best practices or alternative approaches for handling multiple video playback on a webpage?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

do they stop at the end of the video perhaps?

@Jaromanda X thanks for the reply. they stop mid video

I suppose your best bet is to subscribe to the canplay or canplaythrough events, and once that has fired for all the videos, you call the play method on them. Not sure if those events will fire automatically though, even if preload is set to auto, you'd have to test that. If not, you might need to embed all your videos with autoplay to trigger the browser into loading them, and then pause them once the playing event fires ...
